# Пытался решить проект Эйлера, задача 4 на Python

Tags: python

В месте с ошибкой выдает "List index out of range", хотя через "else" должны проходить только шестизначные числа, а значит обращение к [5] должно нормально работать. Исправление [5] на [4] дает результат, следственно проблема в этом, но при такой замене теряется весь смысл.

```
def pal():
    for i in range (100, 1000):
        for x in range(100, 1000):
           nums =  [int(z) for z in str(x*i)]
           if x*i % 10000 < 10:
                if nums[0] == nums[3] and nums[1] == nums[4]:
                    pals.append(x*i)
           else:
#ошибка здесь
                if nums[0] == nums[5] and nums[1] == nums[4] and nums[2] == nums[3]:
                    pals.append(x*i)
pal()
print(pals)
```

Comment: Ошибка со второй же итерации: `100*101 % 10000 = 100`. В блоке `else` пятизначное число `10100`.

Comment: Совет: если что-то работает не так, выводи значения на печать. В данном случае, чтобы, например, выяснить а действительно ли там шестизначное число?

Comment: Второй совет (конкретно по этой задаче): вложеный цикл делай не от 100, а от i, чтобы не проверять дважды одинаковые комбинации.

Comment: Кстати, какой-то сложный способ. Раз уж решили приводить к строке, то проверить на палиндром можно так: `x == x[::-1]`. Ответ на задачу: `906609`.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в индексации массива, довольно большое количество чисел будут пятизначными.

Ошибки можно избежать, если упростить код. Проверять на палиндром можно сравнением строки с её перевёрнутой копией. Также можно уменьшить количество итераций вложенного цикла, если начинать их с `i`.

***Пример:***

```py
m = 0
for i in range(100, 1000):
    for j in range(i, 1000):
        x = str(i*j)
        if x == x[::-1] and int(x) > m:
            m = int(x)
print(m)
```

***stdout:***

```py
906609
```

Answer (score 0):

Если написали "через "else" должны проходить только шестизначные числа", то надо отобразить это в коде. Вот так:

```
...
           else:
                assert len(nums) == 6
                if nums[0] == nums[5] and nums[1] == nums[4] and nums[2] == nums[3]:
...
```

А как `assert` упадет, искать ошибки - почему ваше предположение и реальность расходятся.

Answer (score -1):

```py
lst = []

for i in range(100, 1000):
    for j in range(100, 1000):
    s = str(i * j)
    if s == s[::-1]:
        lst.append(int(s))
print(max(lst))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Плохое решение. Неоптимально ни по времени, ни по памяти